# Jquery: Validate dynamic added field in MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, jquery

I'm adding controls dynamically and want to perform validation on form submission. As simple as want unobtrusive validation to occur on dynamic added controls. logic is below:

**Model:**

```
public List<MyCollection> MyColl {get;set;}
```

am opening partial view in jquery dialog.

**Jquery:**

> //Add control dynamically 
>   var length=0; 
>   //logic to increase length every time on new row added

```
$(".myDiv").append("<tr><input type=text id=MyColl[' + length + '].Field1 name=MyColl[' + length + '].Field1></tr>")
```

I don't know how to specify unobtrusive in this situation? any help would be appreciated.